# Alignment algorithm

Tags: r, algorithms, similarities

I am looking for an algorithm that can align a vector of numbers . I don't know exactly where to look because I am not sure how you would name it, so I am sorry if this is already asked (I couldn't find it).

For example, consider the following example (df data: https://pastebin.com/guWGThsT) where peaks are shifted slightly and you can clearly see how they should align. The objective would be to return how much you need to shift the observations (e.g. in a certain window) in order to make the variables most similar to each other. I think of it as illustrator's horizontal/vertical allign.

Are there standard algorithm to do this?   I am working mostly in R so R code is also helpful.

`image(df):` 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would my post the solution that I took for now. It is based on a shifting each variable to maximise the Pearson between that variable and a template. Where the template was defined as the variable that had the largest sum of all Pearson correlations.  `rowMaxs(cor(df))`;

```
# https://rdrr.io/cran/diffrprojects/src/R/tools.R
shift <- function(x, n=0, default=NA, invert=FALSE){
  n <-
    switch (
      as.character(n),
      right    =  1,
      left     = -1,
      forward  =  1,
      backward = -1,
      lag      =  1,
      lead     = -1,
      as.numeric(n)
    )
  if( length(x) <= abs(n) ){
    if(n < 0){
      n <- -1 * length(x)
    }else{
      n <- length(x)
    }
  }
  if(n==0){
    return(x)
  }
  n <- ifelse(invert, n*(-1), n)
  if(n<0){
    n <- abs(n)
    forward=FALSE
  }else{
    forward=TRUE
  }
  if(forward){
    return(c(rep(default, n), x[seq_len(length(x)-n)]))
  }
  if(!forward){
    return(c(x[seq_len(length(x)-n)+n], rep(default, n)))
  }
}


find.max <- function(target,ref,istart,iend){
  c <- unlist(lapply(-(istart-1):(istart),function(i) cor(target[(istart+i):(iend+i)],ref[istart:iend])))
  return(which.max(c))
}


window.finetune=25

dfy<-df

i.template <- which.max(rowSums(cor(dfy))) # define template according to the maxium sum of R. 
istart=round((nrow(dfy)/2))-window.finetune
iend=round((nrow(dfy)/2))+window.finetune

for (i in 1:ncol(dfy)){
  i.max <- find.max(target=dfy[,i],ref=dfy[,i.template],istart,iend)
  s <- (i.max-istart)
  dfy[,i] <- shift(dfy[,i],-s,default = 0)
  
}

image(dfy)
```

[image]